# VS 2015 Update 1 freezing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I had the issue on my notebook that visual studio would freeze when I open a solution who contains a UWP and two Xamarin Projects. Asp.net still works fine.

I thought maybe the installation is corrupt or there is an issue with Resharper. But I have the same issue now on another notebook who has a completly fresh installation and no Resharper installed so far.
I never had this with VS before Update 1. Any idea what might causing this?

EDIT: Turns out it was the Xamarin Plugin. After deinstall it, it works again..

Comment: Disable add-ins, then re-enable them one by one. That way you can find out which one is the issue.

Comment: Start Visual Studio in diagnostic mode.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with the latest update of the Xamarin VS plugin.